# Poor Performance of asp GridView page changing

Tags: c#, gridview, dataview

In particulare my Webpart from sharepoint get the object array from a WS.

My page changing function where dv is a DataView:

```
protected void gvList_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
              gvList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
              gvList.DataSource = dv;
              gvList.DataBind();
        }
```

My view :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
OnPageIndexChanging="gvList_PageIndexChanging" 
OnSorting="gvListaTickets_Sorting" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" PagerStyle-
CssClass="Pagination" EnableViewState="false">`
```

How I populate DataView:

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(listAll.GetType());
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    serializer.Serialize(sw, listAll);

    ds = new DataSet();
    System.IO.StringReader reader = new System.IO.StringReader(sw.ToString());
    ds.ReadXml(reader);

    if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
       dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
       gvList.DataSource = dv;
       gvList.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: The xml has the full list? is there a way you can get a shorter xml?

Comment: The issue also comes with a small xml (11 records)